# Is opencv interrupting serial communication with arduino?

Tags: c++, opencv, arduino, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I am trying to make a program that uses servos connected to an arduino that follows your face. I'm using visual c++ in visual studio 2017 with opencv 4.1 to do the facial recognition, then sending the location of the identified face to an arduino via serial connection.

I'm new to opencv so I've been going through many tutorials to try to make a code that works.

The plan is to do the facial recognition then calculate the location of the face in visual studio. Then combine the x and y locations to a single string and send it to the arduino with serial. The arduino then splits the coordinates, separated by a colon, using strtok(). It then will move servos accordingly to keep the tracked face in center screen.

I have tested the serial comm in a separate c++ project and it seems to work fine with the current arduino code (not anywhere near finished because I ran into a hiccup wiyh serial comm) except when I send the location string, the servo moves to the desired spot then returns to its starting location.

When I try to implement the serial communication in the project with opencv, it sends the location once, then appears to stop sending serial commands. I've tried debugging by manually, by calling the sendSerial function in other locations, to see if I can get it to send. I've tried looking around for solutions but haven't found any definite solutions other than it may be the waitKey(10) function. If this is so, is there a way around this?

Thanks.

```cpp
###############SerialPort.h##############
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#define ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME 2000
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 255

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class SerialPort
{
private:
    HANDLE handler;
    bool connected;
    COMSTAT status;
    DWORD errors;
public:
    SerialPort(char *portName);
    ~SerialPort();

    int readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool writeSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool isConnected();
};

#endif // SERIALPORT_H
```

```
#################SerialSource.cpp##################
#include "SerialPort.h"

SerialPort::SerialPort(char *portName)
{
    this->connected = false;

    this->handler = CreateFileA(static_cast<LPCSTR>(portName),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    if (this->handler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available\n", portName);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR!!!");
        }
    }
    else {
        DCB dcbSerialParameters = { 0 };

        if (!GetCommState(this->handler, &dcbSerialParameters)) {
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters");
        }
        else {
            dcbSerialParameters.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
            dcbSerialParameters.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
            dcbSerialParameters.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

            if (!SetCommState(handler, &dcbSerialParameters))
            {
                printf("ALERT: could not set Serial port parameters\n");
            }
            else {
                this->connected = true;
                PurgeComm(this->handler, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    if (this->connected) {
        this->connected = false;
        CloseHandle(this->handler);
    }
}

int SerialPort::readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesRead;
    unsigned int toRead = 0;

    ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);

    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0) {
        if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size) {
            toRead = buf_size;
        }
        else toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
    }

    if (ReadFile(this->handler, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) return bytesRead;

    return 0;
}

bool SerialPort::writeSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    if (!WriteFile(this->handler, (void*)buffer, buf_size, &bytesSend, 0)) {
        ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

bool SerialPort::isConnected()
{
    return this->connected;
}
```

```
###################faceDetect.cpp################
// CPP program to detects face in a video 

// Include required header files from OpenCV directory 
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SerialPort.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


//Set up serial comm
char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
char port[] = "\\\\.\\COM3";
char incoming[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];


// Function for Face Detection 
void detectAndDraw(Mat& img, CascadeClassifier& cascade, double scale, SerialPort arduino);
string cascadeName;

// Function for sending locations to arduino
void sendSerial(string locations, SerialPort arduino);






int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    //Establish connection to serial
    SerialPort arduino(port);

    if (arduino.isConnected()) {
        cout << "COnnection Established" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error in port name" << endl;
    }

    // VideoCapture class for playing video for which faces to be detected 
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame, image;

    // PreDefined trained XML classifiers with facial features 
    CascadeClassifier cascade;
    double scale = 1;


    // Change path before execution  
    cascade.load("C:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    // Start Video..1) 0 for WebCam 2) "Path to Video" for a Local Video 
    capture.open(CAP_MSMF);
    //sendSerial("400:100", arduino);
    if (capture.isOpened())
    {
        // Capture frames from video and detect faces 
        cout << "Face Detection Started...." << endl;
        while (1)
        {
            capture >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;
            Mat frame1 = frame.clone();
            detectAndDraw(frame1, cascade, scale, arduino);
            char c = (char)waitKey(10);



            // Press q to exit from window 
            if (c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Could not Open Camera";
    return 0;
}



void sendSerial(string locations, SerialPort arduino) {
    //string command;
    //command = to_string(xloc);




    cout << locations << endl;

    char *charArray = new char[locations.size() + 1];
    copy(locations.begin(), locations.end(), charArray);
    charArray[locations.size()] = '\n';

    arduino.writeSerialPort(charArray, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);



    //arduino.readSerialPort(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

    //cout << output;

    delete[] charArray;


    //
    //command = to_string(yloc);
    //copy(command.begin(), command.end(), charArray);
    //charArray[command.size()] = '\n';

    //arduino.writeSerialPort(charArray, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
    ////arduino.readSerialPort(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

    ////cout << output;

    //delete[] charArray;
}


void detectAndDraw(Mat& img, CascadeClassifier& cascade,
    double scale, SerialPort arduino)
{
    vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat gray, smallImg;

    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // Convert to Gray Scale 
    double fx = 1 / scale;

    // Resize the Grayscale Image  
    resize(gray, smallImg, Size(), fx, fx, INTER_LINEAR);
    equalizeHist(smallImg, smallImg);

    // Detect faces of different sizes using cascade classifier  
    cascade.detectMultiScale(smallImg, faces, 1.1,
        2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    // Draw circles around the faces 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = faces[i];
        Mat smallImgROI;


        int x = faces[i].x;
        int y = faces[i].y;
        int h = y + faces[i].height;
        int w = x + faces[i].width;
        int centerX = x + (.5* faces[i].width);
        int centerY = y + (.5* faces[i].height);

        if (abs(320 - centerX) <= 50) {
            if (abs(240 - centerY) <= 50) {
                rectangle(img,
                    Point(x, y),
                    Point(w, h),
                    Scalar(0, 0, 275),
                    2,
                    8,
                    0);
            }
        }

        else {
            rectangle(img,
                Point(x, y),
                Point(w, h),
                Scalar(275, 275, 275),
                2,
                8,
                0);

        }


        stringstream stringX;
        stringstream stringY;
        stringX << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << centerX;
        stringY << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << centerY;

        std::stringstream ss;
        //ss << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << centerX << ":"<< centerY;
        //std::string s = ss.str();
        std::string s = stringX.str() + ":" + stringY.str();
        //cout << s << endl;
        sendSerial(s, arduino);

        smallImgROI = smallImg(r);


        if (arduino.isConnected()) {
            cout << "COnnection Established" << endl;
            //sendSerial("400:100", arduino);
        }

    }

    // Show Processed Image with detected faces 
    imshow("Face Detection", img);
}
```

```
#####################arduino code################
#include <Servo.h>

String input;
char array[6];
char *strings[3];
char *ptr = NULL;
int xloc;
int yloc;

int hServoPin = 9;
Servo hServo;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
  //set up servos
  hServo.attach(hServoPin);

  //start serial connection
  Serial.begin(9600);


  //***** delete later *****
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {



  if(Serial.available()){

    //grab "xloc:yloc" and convert to char array
    input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');


    //delete later
    //Serial.print("input; ");
    //Serial.println(input);

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
        array[i] = input.charAt(i);
        //Serial.print(array[i]);
    }


    //split char array into two entities
    byte index = 0;
    ptr = strtok(array, ":;");  // takes a list of delimiters

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        strings[index] = ptr;
        index++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ":;");  // takes a list of delimiters
        //Serial.println("loop");
    }

    //set xloc and yloc respectively
    xloc = atoi(strings[0]);
    yloc = atoi(strings[1]);



  }

  if((xloc < 214)){
    hServo.write(0);
    delay(100);
  }
  else if((xloc > 214) && (xloc < 328)){
    hServo.write(90);
    delay(100);
  }
  else if((xloc > 328)){
    hServo.write(180);
    delay(100);
  }


}
```

Comment: sendSerial() is called within the face processing loop.  If there are no faces, then it doesn't happen; and if there are several faces, they go to sendSerial() one after the other in each frame.

Comment: Should it not be called in the face processing loop?

Comment: Say there happen to be two faces present and detected.  In the current setup, we send the coordinates of face[0], then face[1], then waitKey(10), and repeat.  If the servo chases the latest coordinates, it could keep alternating between face[0] and face[1], which may be undesirable.  I don't see anything wrong with the usage of waitKey() or imshow().  Perhaps every frame is empty but the first?